# is is possible to drop voltage without knowing a components amperage

Tags: resistors, circuit-design, load

I am new to circuits/electrical stuff

Correct me if i am wrong.

if i have an led (2.1V / 0.02A) and if i give it 0.02A it will only take 2.1V or if i give it 2.1V it will take 0.02A

Ohms law (\$I=\frac{V}{R}\$).

If start with 9V i can use ohms law to get the correct power for the led because i know how many amps it requires

My question is:

If i started with 9V. Could i drop the voltage down for a component that takes 5V without knowing how many amps it uses?

Sub-question:

[image]

Wouldn't a circuit like this drain a battery or cause the circuit to short out?

Comment: This is the purpose of voltage regulators.

Comment: The voltage specification for an LED is usually the nominal **measured** voltage when the LED is driven with a specific current. If you drive 20mA you should see **about** 2.1V across the LED, with maybe 10% variation for different LEDs from the same batch. If you drive 2.1V across the LED you would expect an **average** current of 20mA across many different parts but the minimum and maximum extremes could be large. In practice, we try to drive an LED with a specified current, not a specified voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a voltage dropper with two resistors. Just assume (a fairly accurate assumption I might add) that, the LED has 2.1 volts across it then, put a resistor in series with it to the 9 volt rail. The value of the resistor sets the current: -

$$I = \dfrac{\text{9 volts - 2.1 volts}}{R} = \dfrac{6.9}{R} = \text{20 mA}$$

Rearrange to find R (it equals 345 ohms).

> *Wouldn't a circuit like this drain a battery or cause the circuit to
> short out?*

It's extremely sub-optimal.

> *If i started with 9V. Could i drop the voltage down for a component
> that takes 5V without knowing how many amps it uses?*

You could (and waste a lot of power) or, just use a voltage regulator - that is what they are for.